# what is the purpose of the suffix 'ish' at the end of the adjectives 'girlish' and 'boyish'

Tags: meaning, terminology

Hi could anyone tell me what is the purpose of the suffix 'ish' at the end of the adjectives 'girlish' and 'boyish? I mean you could use the suffix 'ly' but what is the need of the ish? I know that it indicates that the person being described is not entirely behaving like a 'girl' or 'boy' but can anyone shed any light on the actual purpose? I would be grateful if you could direct me to any literature or references to support.

Thank you! :)

Comment: The word *boyish* does not mean "not entirely like a boy" in the way *reddish* means "not entirely red" (although certainly girls and grown-up boys can behave boyishly). The difference is that *boy* is a noun and *red* is an adjective. [See the dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ish?searchDictCode=all).

Comment: "Boyly" would sound weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-ish: resembling, like, having some attributes of

Check out [Unpack Your Adjectives](http://youtu.be/NkuuZEey_bs). It's not a definitive source by any means, but it does mention and illustrate 'boyish'.

Usually when we say 'boyish' or 'girlish', we're referring to a youthful male/female (appearance as appropriate) and use it with a positive connotation.

- "No cake for me, thank you. Trying to keep my girlish figure."
- With that boyish charm, you'd never guess he was 45.

However, in George RR Martin's *A Song of Fire and Ice* books (*Game of Thrones* television series), the character Brienne is often ridiculed for her *mannish* ways and appearance. Likewise, in the animated series *Archer*, Lana's mannish hands are a constant source of jokes.

It would probably be similarly insulting for a girl to be called "boyish" or a boy to be called "girlish," but I don't have an example to give you off the top of my head.

Comment: +1, but "boyish" is not necessarily insulting to girls the way "girlish" would be to boys. "Mannish" would be insulting to women, however, as you suggest.

Comment: @Robusto thank you :) I'm new to this so didn't know I could click the tick :) thanks!